# Pandas equivalent for SQL - arithmetic expression within aggregate function

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am a pandas newbie coming from a SQL background although have some exposure to Python.

I was wondering if there is a simple way to do the following SQL code in pandas dataframe:

```
Select
  A,
  Sum(B/C) value
From
  Table
Group by
  A
```

Below is all I got so far there doesn't seem to be a syntax to include arithmetic expressions:

```
df.groupby(['A']).sum()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sushanth Thank you, that is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Sushanth Please post it as an answer, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
df.assign(value = df.B.div(df.C)).groupby('A')['value'].sum()
```